# Monty Hall simulation issue regarding arrays

Tags: arrays, logic, simulation

I am running into an issue with a simulation I did of the "Montey Hall" statistics riddle.  I should get consistent results for my answer (33%/66%), but every third time I run the simulation the results end up being 0/100 and then they flip to to 66%/33%.  I believe the issue might be with how I am creating my arrays (i.e the results of one simulation are bleeding over into the next simulation), but I can't pinpoint the issue. Also, if you have any tips on a better way to write my simulation, I would appreciate that as well.

Below is my code

```perl
#simulates guessing a door
def sim_guess(nsim):
    answer = []
    guess = [0,1,2]
    stratagy = [0.2,0.6,0.2]
    for element in range(nsim):
        answer.append(np.random.choice(guess, p=stratagy))
    return answer

#simulates placing the prize
def simulate_prizedoor(nsim):
    doors = [0,1,2]
    answer = []
    for element in range(nsim):
        answer.append(np.random.choice(doors))
    return answer

#simulates opening a door to reveal a goat
def goat_door(prize, guess):
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(prize)):
        door = [0,1,2]
        if prize[i] == guess[i]:
            door.remove(prize[i])
            answer.append(np.random.choice(door))
        else:
            door.remove(prize[i])
            door.remove(guess[i])
            answer.append(door[0])
    return answer

#simulates changing guess after goat has been revealed
def switch_guess(goat, guess):
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(goat)):
        door = [0,1,2]
        door.remove(goat[i])
        door.remove(guess[i])
        answer.append(door[0])
    return answer
#shows percentages after 10,000 trials
def win_percentage(prize, guess):
    wins = []
    for element in prize:
        wins.append(prize[element] == guess[element])

    answer = (float(np.sum(wins))/len(guess))*100
    return answer

prize = simulate_prizedoor(10000)
guess = sim_guess(10000)

#wins without changing guess
print win_percentage(prize, guess)

#wins with changing guess
goat = goat_door(prize, guess)
switch = switch_guess(goat, guess)
print win_percentage(prize, switch)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this would be a lot easier to do with objects, as each game is separate from the others.  I would probably do it something like

```
import random

class Game:
        winningDoor = 0
        chosenDoor = 0
        goat = 0
        def __init__(self):
                self.winningDoor = random.randint(1,3)
        def play(self, move, willSwap):
                self.chosenDoor = move
                self.goat = 0
                i=1
                while(self.goat <= 0):
                        if(i != self.winningDoor and i != self.chosenDoor):
                                self.goat = i
                        i += 1
                if(willSwap):
                        self.chosenDoor = 6-(self.chosenDoor + self.goat)
                return (self.winningDoor == self.chosenDoor)


def main():
        swapwins = 0
        staywins = 0
        for i in range(0,10000):
                testswap = Game()
                if(testswap.play(random.randint(1,3), 1)):
                        swapwins += 1
                teststay = Game()
                if(teststay.play(random.randint(1,3), 0)):
                        staywins += 1
        print swapwins, staywins

main()
```

Here, each game is made separately, with each game being played once.  It's not the most efficient use of objects, and could probably be just a subroutine for this, but if you want more statistics, this will end up being much better.  The only potentially confusing thing here would be

```
self.chosenDoor = 6-(self.chosenDoor + self.goat)
```

which is a simplification of the statement that if goat is 1 and 2 was chosen, change it to 3; if goat was 2 and 3 was chosen, change it to 1; if goat was 3 and chosen was 1, change it to 2; etc...
As far as why your original code didn't work, returning all of your things in groups of 10000 looks very odd and difficult to debug.  your random numbers could also be accomplished with randint, which would also make your code more human-readable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I really like what you did using objects instead of arrays.